# assign image to category and it's posts on WordPress

Tags: image, wordpress, categories, posts, assign

I want to assign an image to a category and it's posts on WordPress. When adding the new post it will take the image and assign to it's container category. If you have any way to help or plug-in to do that, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think you are trying to show posts (or maybe post excerpts) from multiple categories in a single list and include images in these posts based on their individual categories.

If there is only one place you are trying to display these images and if they will not change very often, you could include some conditionals directly in The Loop.

```
<!-- Test to see if the post is in a given cat and apply a custom class for styling -->
<?php if ( in_category('CATNUMBER') ) { ?>
    <div class="SOME-CUSTOM-STYLE">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="GENERIC-NON-STYLED-POST">
<?php } ?>
```

Once you have custom classes on the divs by category number, you can style a background image in your CSS. Alternately, you could spit out an  tag right in the loop.

If you foresee adding new categories and/or changing pictures often, you will probably want a cleaner way of doing this. If you only have a handful of categories or if you are comfortable making changes to the loop often, this would work fine.

Comment: i want to assign thumnail to category and by default it children "posts" take it as featured image without needing to sssign featured image each time